# Create a Multiplayer Minecraft server and allow my Mod to be used in Minecraft Forge

Tags: server, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I made a Mod where I created my custom Blocks and commands and now I have it ready. I was able to use it in Single Player in Minecraft by installing my Mod. But What I want to do is to create a multiplayer Minecraft server which would allow many players to use my Mod. Does anyone have an idea about how to do this? I think I am having this trouble because I don't understand the difference between server and client side in Forge, and I don't know if my Mod is client or server side. I hope someone can help figure this out :)
Best,
Sara.

Answer (score 1):

A mod runs in two places:

On the **Server** where it does the actual map modification, inventory updates, etc...
That all gets saved, processed and updated on the server.

On the **Client** all rendering happens. This is where the mobs move, blocks get their images/textures, sounds are played, etc..

Now there is some overlap between server and client, because the client tries to "predict" what will happen on the server(block removed, block replaced) etc... but the chanes the client predicted will happen will get overridden the moment the server pushes a chunk update to the client.

Server is ALWAYS leading. Client always follows. Never the other way around.
If it doesn't happen on the server, it simply hasn't happened for the other players.

That's why you do checks like `if(!world.isRemote())` to test if you are really on the server.

Try to keep world modifying code on the server. It will push the updates automatically to the client. Do your block replace, block dig, block set to air all within a

```
if(!world.isRemote()) {
    world.setBlockToAir(new BlocPos(1,1,1));
    // whatever world modifying code there is.
}
```

if you need to do clientside rendering stuff, do that all on the client side.
Use the client proxy for that and have empty methods for that in the normal proxy that also get executed on the server.

read  [www.minecraftforge.net/wiki/Proxies](http://www.minecraftforge.net/wiki/Proxies)

```
myMod.proxy.spawnSparklyThingies(new BlockPos(3,3,3));
```

To do things you only want to render on the client.

When you are in a single player world, the server and client are merged. Yet you should code your mod as if they aren't merged so they can be used on servers too.

In eclipse under the run option is a arrow next to it, if you click it you can choose to run a server instance.
Run it, set it up(accept eula.txt) and then start up a client instance and connect to the server to test yoru mod.
Things can get a lot more complicated than that, but this should give you a small base in differentiating between server and client.